# Opencv всегда возвращает False в функции cv2.VideoCapture("files/new.mp4")

Tags: python, docker, opencv, ffmpeg

Собрал докер с ffmpeg и opencv, когда пытаюсь запустить

```
python3.7 -c 'import cv2; cap = cv2.VideoCapture("files/new.mp4"); print(cap.isOpened());'
```

Выдает False. Но если на вход даю картинку, вместо видео

```
python3.7 -c 'import cv2; cap = cv2.VideoCapture("files/img.png"); print(cap.isOpened());'
```

То выдает размеры картинки и читает её.
Как мне сделать так, что бы и видео читало. Код докера ниже:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility

ENV NUM_CORES 4

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt install libgl1-mesa-glx nasm git yasm cmake libtheora-dev opus-tools -y

RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3.7 -m pip install opencv-python
RUN python3.7 -m pip install easydict
RUN python3.7 -m pip install firebase_admin
RUN python3.7 -m pip install pyyaml
RUN python3.7 -m pip install tqdm
RUN python3.7 -m pip install google.cloud-storage google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

WORKDIR /usr/local/src

RUN git clone https://github.com/l-smash/l-smash.git \
    && git clone https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264.git \
    && git clone https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265_git.git \
    && git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git \
    #&& git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git \
    #&& git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git \
    && git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac.git \
    && git clone --depth 1 https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx \
    && git clone https://github.com/xiph/opus.git

RUN wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.5.1.zip -O opencv.zip --progress=bar:force:noscroll --no-check-certificate && \
    unzip -q opencv.zip && \
    rm opencv.zip && \
    wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/4.5.1.zip -O opencv_contrib.zip --progress=bar:force:noscroll --no-check-certificate && \
    unzip -q opencv_contrib.zip && \
    rm opencv_contrib.zip

# Build L-SMASH
# =================================
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/l-smash
RUN ./configure \
    && make -j ${NUM_CORES} \
    && make install
# =================================


# Build libx264
# =================================
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/x264
RUN ./configure --enable-static \
    && make -j ${NUM_CORES} \
    && make install
# =================================


# Build libx265
# =================================
WORKDIR  /usr/local/src/x265_git/build/linux
RUN cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr ../../source \
    && make -j ${NUM_CORES} \
    && make install
# =================================

# Build libfdk-aac
# =================================
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/fdk-aac
RUN autoreconf -fiv \
    && ./configure --disable-shared \
    && make -j ${NUM_CORES} \
    && make install
# =================================

# Build libvpx
# =================================
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/libvpx
RUN ./configure --disable-examples \
    && make -j ${NUM_CORES} \
    && make install
# =================================

# Build libopus
# =================================
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/opus
RUN ./autogen.sh \
    && ./configure --disable-shared \
    && make -j ${NUM_CORES} \
    && make install
# =================================

WORKDIR /usr/local/src
RUN wget -c https://downloads.xiph.org/releases/ogg/libogg-1.3.4.tar.gz && tar zxvf libogg-1.3.4.tar.gz && cd libogg-1.3.4 && ./configure && make -j ${NUM_CORES} && make install && cd ..

WORKDIR /usr/local/src
RUN git clone https://github.com/gypified/libmp3lame.git && cd libmp3lame && ./configure && make -j ${NUM_CORES} && make install

WORKDIR /usr/local/src
RUN wget -c http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis/libvorbis-1.3.6.tar.gz && tar zxvf libvorbis-1.3.6.tar.gz && cd libvorbis-1.3.6 && ./configure && make -j ${NUM_CORES} && make install && cd ..

# Build OpenCV 3.x
# =================================
#RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y --force-yes libopencv-dev
RUN python3.7 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade numpy
WORKDIR /usr/local/src
RUN cd opencv-4.5.1 && mkdir release && cd release && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
          -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
          -D WITH_TBB=ON \
          -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
          -D WITH_V4L=ON \
          -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
          -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON \
          -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-4.5.1/modules \
          ..

WORKDIR /usr/local/src/opencv-4.5.1/release
RUN make -j ${NUM_CORES} \
    && make install \
    && sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf' \
    && ldconfig


# =================================

# Build ffmpeg.
# =================================
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
    libass-dev



#            --enable-libx265 - Does not work on recent builds
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/ffmpeg
RUN ./configure --extra-libs="-ldl" \
            --enable-gpl \
            --enable-libass \
            --enable-libfdk-aac \
            --enable-libfontconfig \
            --enable-libfreetype \
            --enable-libfribidi \
            --enable-libmp3lame \
            #--enable-libopus \
            --enable-libtheora \
            --enable-libvorbis \
            --enable-libvpx \
            --enable-libx264 \
            --enable-nonfree \
    && make -j ${NUM_CORES} \
    && make install
# =================================


# Remove all tmpfile
# =================================
WORKDIR /usr/local/
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/src
# =================================


RUN python3.7 -m pip install torch==1.7.1+cu110 torchvision==0.8.2+cu110 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html


COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN python3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: А так: `cv2.VideoCapture("files/new.mp4", cv::CAP_FFMPEG);`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin , Выдает SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Если делаю `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("files/new.mp4", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG);` То тоже false

Answer (score 0):

Переписал докер, всё заработало. Спасибо @AlexanderChernin за помощь, ты подал мне классную идею как исправить и научил меня чему то новому.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt install libgl1-mesa-glx -y
RUN apt-get install wget libsm6 libxext6 build-essential yasm cmake libtool libc6 libc6-dev unzip libnuma1 libnuma-dev x264 libx264-dev -y

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.7
ARG OPENCV_VERSION=4.5.1

# Needed for string substitution
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
# https://techoverflow.net/2019/05/18/how-to-fix-configuring-tzdata-interactive-input-when-building-docker-images/
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Europe/Prague

# Install all dependencies for OpenCV

# add sources for older pythons
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
# Install all dependencies for OpenCV
RUN apt-get -y update -qq --fix-missing && \
    apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
        python${PYTHON_VERSION} \
        python${PYTHON_VERSION}-dev \
        $( [ ${PYTHON_VERSION%%.*} -ge 3 ] && echo "python${PYTHON_VERSION%%.*}-distutils" ) \
        wget \
        unzip \
        cmake \
        ffmpeg \
        libtbb2 \
        gfortran \
        apt-utils \
        pkg-config \
        checkinstall \
        qt5-default \
        build-essential \
        libopenblas-base \
        libopenblas-dev \
        liblapack-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
        #libgtk-3-dev \
        #libavcodec58 \
        libavcodec-dev \
        #libavformat58 \
        libavformat-dev \
        libavutil-dev \
        #libswscale5 \
        libswscale-dev \
        libjpeg8-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libtiff5-dev \
        #libdc1394-22 \
        libdc1394-22-dev \
        libxine2-dev \
        libv4l-dev \
        libgstreamer1.0 \
        libgstreamer1.0-dev \
        libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 \
        libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
        libglew-dev \
        libpostproc-dev \
        libeigen3-dev \
        libtbb-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libsm6 \
        libxext6 \
        libxrender1 \
        git

# install python dependencies
    # sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 && \
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --progress=bar:force:noscroll --no-check-certificate && \
    python${PYTHON_VERSION} get-pip.py && \
    rm get-pip.py && \
    pip${PYTHON_VERSION} install numpy

# Install OpenCV
RUN wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip -O opencv.zip --progress=bar:force:noscroll --no-check-certificate && \
    unzip -q opencv.zip && \
    mv /opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION} /opencv && \
    rm opencv.zip && \
    wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip -O opencv_contrib.zip --progress=bar:force:noscroll --no-check-certificate && \
    unzip -q opencv_contrib.zip && \
    mv /opencv_contrib-${OPENCV_VERSION} /opencv_contrib && \
    rm opencv_contrib.zip

# Prepare build
RUN mkdir /opencv/build && \
    cd /opencv/build && \
    cmake \
      -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
      -D BUILD_DOCS=ON \
      -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
      -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opencv_contrib/modules \
      -D BUILD_opencv_python3=$( [ ${PYTHON_VERSION%%.*} -ge 3 ] && echo "ON" || echo "OFF" ) \
      -D BUILD_opencv_python2=$( [ ${PYTHON_VERSION%%.*} -lt 3 ] && echo "ON" || echo "OFF" ) \
      -D PYTHON${PYTHON_VERSION%%.*}_EXECUTABLE=$(which python${PYTHON_VERSION}) \
      -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=$(which python${PYTHON_VERSION}) \
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
      -D WITH_IPP=OFF \
      -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
      -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
      -D WITH_V4L=ON \
      -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON \
      -D WITH_TBB=ON \
      -D WITH_QT=ON \
      -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
      -D WITH_LAPACK=ON \
      #-D WITH_HPX=ON \
      -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
      ..

# Build, Test and Install
RUN cd /opencv/build && \
    make -j$(nproc) && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig

# cleaning
RUN apt-get -y remove \
        unzip \
        cmake \
        gfortran \
        apt-utils \
        pkg-config \
        checkinstall \
        build-essential \
        libopenblas-dev \
        liblapack-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
        #libgtk-3-dev \
        libavcodec-dev \
        libavformat-dev \
        libavutil-dev \
        libswscale-dev \
        libjpeg8-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libtiff5-dev \
        libdc1394-22-dev \
        libxine2-dev \
        libv4l-dev \
        libgstreamer1.0-dev \
        libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
        libglew-dev \
        libpostproc-dev \
        libeigen3-dev \
        libtbb-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
    && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /opencv /opencv_contrib /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```